# Typeguard for generic union type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have created a union type:

```
type RequestParameterType = number | string | boolean | Array<number>;
```

and I have a class which is a key/value pair holding that union type:

```
class RequestParameter
{
    constructor(name: string, value: RequestParameterType)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public Name: string;
    public Value: RequestParameterType;
}
```

I can then make an array of that RequestParameter to hold keys/values:

```
let parameters: Array<RequestParameter> = new Array<RequestParameter>();
parameters.push(new RequestParameter("one", 1));
parameters.push(new RequestParameter("two", "param2"));
```

with the idea being that I can write a `GetParameter` function to return typed values from that array, which in practice I'd probably use like this:

```
// should return number type, with value 1
let numberParam: number | undefined = this.GetParameter<number>("one", parameters);

// should return string type, with value "param2"
let stringParam: string | undefined = this.GetParameter<string>("two", parameters);

// should return undefined, because param named 'two' is not number type
let undefinedParam: number | undefined = this.GetParameter<number>("two", parameters);
```

However I'm having an issue with my function to get typed parameters, because I don't know how to check the generic type matches the value type:

```
function GetParameter<T extends RequestParameterType>(parameterName: string, parameters: Array<RequestParameter>): T | undefined
{
    let result: T | undefined = undefined;

    for (let parameter of parameters)
    {
        // Type check fails: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
        if (parameter.Name === parameterName && parameter.Value instanceof T )
        {
            // Possibly an issue here too: 
            // Type 'RequestParameterType' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.  
            // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.
            result = parameter.Value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I believe I may need to write a typeguard function, but I'm struggling in the same way to check the generic type when writing the typeguard. Is this going to be possible to resolve?

Here is the example : [in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYAFAhgJ0wWwmAmwBVxoBeKAO0TwCNioAfKNbAS2oHMWp6A9gIA2ETNT4BBbLhAAeWg2IA+ANwAodQGNhmFClgJkaLLgJFs6gN7qAkFoHV2iLcAHYAFNXwQAXG2BOHgAaKAA3TGFkfzgkVAwcHwsySABKOxtbW2AACw4UADoAOR8oKm8CDSzc-IKANUjkMvDGiCqAX01bMER6YQ4tKBKCf3YubiqevoGoBqi-QziTRPNiFLb1TvVRYCgwFcJiFH9pWTlY4wSzQ+xlZuoIAHcoU8x5C-jTJJUPVI1964WQo9FA5LxPRaXL6rTwAIkcEFhoQAjKk-uoAd9sMDEKDwc8PstAcQPLDgI8BEioLDMXgAEywtEadQAehZbByAkQwgAJlBsIRENgJIpGNgoKBIKFHhxci15lBkdtCDQ6GLof5RUxWIhqDyIAAzLgQPlUGqFADihGhNwUap+8IeVNpNxQ6NZ7NBXN5-MFwoCQV4kog0tlOXlTRpKwZyt2Yx4GoD4z4uv1RoepoleUt1oOFjk8e4ylJ5MpoRdQPdbI53r5AuAQokqcNxp5oUYWkwuOgtJoPj5AHJSwOoPkaAJdlrxcHY1Bm+mTYmpym9S2M81zQUrVcsXalLcSxTnXmju71Abda4OI4oNubfmSFAIAAPIh6gyEncw9bFivEYYLIW5YntiJwyG85xGJ8IHKKk-iPjqq4Ljy1h2DsvooNywDwSuaats086tsytgGu4UAeOhf7igIBp7CBboZHYtgcLRHhUcUpQUFxdHEtgAFQAAZAJPFYvUrSjk4wDiFoEA0VAJDpFkmRZAKmHCLsVDsXMyBVLYnR6V09aNhhWEaJ0QA)

Comment: relevant [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, which is what actually gets run. The type `T` and its specification like `<number>` or `<string>` will be [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) upon compilation, so there's nothing called `T` at runtime to use.  The `instanceof` operator specifically only works when checking against class constructor functions, and since your possible `T` values are mostly primitives like `string` and `boolean`, you wouldn't want to use `instanceof` anyway (`"foo" instanceof String` is `false`).

Instead, you will probably need to pass a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) into `GetParameter()` as an argument, since such a function will exist at runtime.

That is, you could change `GetParameter()` to

```
function GetParameter<T extends RequestParameterType>(
  parameterName: string,
  parameters: Array<RequestParameter>,
  guard: (x: RequestParameterType) => x is T // new param
): T | undefined {
  let result: T | undefined = undefined;

  for (let parameter of parameters) {
    // new check using guard() instead of instanceof
    if (parameter.Name === parameterName && guard(parameter.Value)) {
      result = parameter.Value; // no error
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

where `guard()` has to be a function which can take an object of some `RequestParameterType` and narrow it to `T`.  Here is a set of those you can use:

```
const guards = {
  number: (x: RequestParameterType): x is number => typeof x === "number",
  string: (x: RequestParameterType): x is string => typeof x === "string",
  boolean: (x: RequestParameterType): x is boolean => typeof x === "boolean",

  // the only array matching RequestParameterType is number[], so we can
  // just check to see if x is an array  without needing to inspect elements
  numberArray: (x: RequestParameterType): x is number[] => Array.isArray(x) 
};
```

And then you can call `GetParameter()` like this:

```
let numberParam = GetParameter("one", parameters, guards.number);
console.log(numberParam); // 1

let stringParam = GetParameter("two", parameters, guards.string);
console.log(stringParam); // param2

let undefinedParam = GetParameter("two", parameters, guards.number);
console.log(undefinedParam); // undefined
```

Note how `guards.number` takes the place of `<number>`.  And if you inspect the type of `numberParam` it is `number | undefined`, and the returned values are what you expect.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYAFAhgJ0wWwmAmwBVxoBeKAO0TwCNioAfKNbAS2oHMWp6A9gIA2ETNT4BBbLhAAeWg2IA+ANwAodQGMB1NFG6IcAExRQqAb3VQadRtgBcUABQAPJ3CSoMOfIWJkkACUTq5QHGaK9ubKUKCQAgBmUGEUaVAARFHEGQA01mzAnDxObh4IyGhYuAREpOQhKeFm7Fy8FLHxEElNaVQZrTx5BYIiYtSl7rAV3tV+dYEQjWER-EKi4jFx5D2p6RmjG9TDNtnY0rKT5V5VvrUBDaHNtkrYANoAulsXmCAAdBEfiA3EF1ABfDTaYSYFBmTyVHw1fzYKBWGw6PRFRBaYACbDOah+JyDbi5KAAN0wwmQ1wRc3u9WCqIKNmAAAsIn8AHJ+cw0PwaGysjkoP4ANSpyD5lOpEEFUDBmhsYEQ9GEHC0UB5BGJRTa8pVao1UAlstpszuyMWGkV6kSiGoOI4uigAHFCPTkXISFAIK4iNRTNMboj5g9IMpnAUwJa6tqILriqTo7HiCgnEC5PCLUi6sp8jZDCYrsG6anGUstiszCR1I0fawHcYIIkuBBjMybKJgFBsKhEMJgE4G1Amy22x2qGPW9R25CbIk8S5u1AY7mmD012HsCggp2hRxks4twzuby+qvy-GoAAyG8GIzYYzH8viyVLPdooU2PsoAc9qgT2RN9ZXlGxFXApVe0IRBsAkX9-xtTQVyAup0ygTNs1uddsFiKhZwAdwwmRfizGZsO3SMgg0VC0z+FUUDZAkICIrDQwZZwMl0CA8igABGIJqPUWid3oxBGOY1jyPY5FOOAAiBF4jITwAJgyQTIRXM56T5d0ZLqTjuN4kSUDJIsn1FM4hIxFAxj+YQBG4Ak7GIelqKgAB6Dz+OQwhCiTHSqD0z0DIyeTFLJEyzMfUw-hJazdFs0R7Mc5wSTc1RPO81TfJ7acJ0Ct0PXLOSFOM8tTIfExLJc7AEr0OyHKc-LZ2MDKstHQNx1a9QgA)